# Cause for NullPointerException at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I am getting the following exception from a lot of devices such as 
Sumsung GT-I8190N Android: 4.1.2,
Sumsung GT-I8552  Android: 4.1.2, 
Sumsung GT-I9300  Android: 4.3,
Sumsung GT-S5830  Android: 2.2.1,
Sumsung GT-S7262  Android: 4.1.2,
LGE     LG-P768   Android: 4.0.4,
HUAWEI  G610-U20  Android: 4.2.1,
HUAWEI  G730-U10  Android: 4.2.2,
etc.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(SourceFile:2626)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(SourceFile:3011)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(SourceFile:907)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1992)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1813)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4481)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Also the support library version is `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'`. BTW, I checked that non of `findViewById` functions return null and search a lot to find the same error in internet but no result is found.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: what about posting your code?

Comment: @LaurentMeyer Actually, there is a lot of `RecyclerView`s in my project and I have no clue which of them throws this exception! Also, I got the exception by hockeyapps.net so I even don't know the scenario that this exception caused by!

Answer (score 0):

Hello I guess this kind of error usually fire when you miss to apply setLayoutManager to your recycler view. Make sure you apply layout manager to your recylver view see below example :

```
 mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
 mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
 mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter());
```

Comment: I have a `RecyclerListFragment` abstract class that in `onViewCreated` function I called `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);` so this is not the case, I guess!

Comment: Please edit the question and provide us the more info.

Comment: I hope you understand that you have to share more code info. Might be we can help you. thanks

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I am sure more information would help but unfortunately I have no clue that where this error coming from! Then I don't know what part of the code I should share!! Would you please ask what kind of information do you mean?

Comment: Simply run your application and see when the application crash or thorw this error, Open your relevant activity/fragment  and verify the code

Comment: It's not crashing in my devices!! nor Genymotion devices! As I explained above I got the error from http://hockeyapp.net

Comment: @hadilq create a genymotion emulator or avd similar to device on which it is crashing...meanwhile can you list few devices where it is crashing...

Comment: @ShadowDroid I'm posting more devices. I'll try more to find a scenario for this exception